# SQL Ranking by Sum

Tags: sql, rank

I have data table with the following items:

```
Item#    Description      Company ID     Sales       
----------------------------------------------
1          wigit 1         521           500
2          wigit 2         521           700
1          wigit 1         663           200
2          wigit 2         663           300
3          wigit 3         521           300
```

What I'm trying to do is pull the data in a format that will allow me to see that wigit 1 ranks first in sales for Company 521 but wigit one only ranks 19th in sales to our entire lineup of companies we sell to in a given period of time.  From here I'd provide a sale gap figure of 18 to leadership to see whiles items to which companies could use attention.

the Result I want from the sample table is to pull company 521 vs the whole company

```
Item #  Description  Company 521 Rank   Company 663 Rank Total Ranking      
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          wigit 1               2                2         3
2          wigit 2               1                1         2 
3          wigit 3               3                3         1
```

Hoping this makes some sense, not sure if Possible with Rank or not.   Result would go into Power BI

Comment: Your desired output is not matching with sample data. Can you edit to clear the expected output.

Comment: Changed it up, think that works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `rank()` in a subquery to get the company ranks.  Then an outer aggregation:

```
select Item#, Description,
       max(case when CompanyId = 521 then seqnum_c end) desc) as rank_521,
       max(case when CompanyId = 663 then seqnum_c end) desc) as rank_663,
       rank() over (order by sum(sales) desc) as overall_rank
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by coompanyid order by sales desc) as seqnum_c
      from t
     ) t
group by Item#, Description
```